# ADF: Create Tree Node on click of an option from tree’s context menu

Tags: tree, oracle-adf, treenode

Jdeveloper version – 11.1.1.7.0

I want to create a tree node programmatically on click of an option in the tree’s Context Menu. The node should be created with a default name say ‘Level 1’.

[image: Tree Root Node]

So on loading my page the Tree should be empty and the currently available tree structures  should not be displayed. Only when I create a new record (by clicking on the Insert option from the context menu)  a node should get created.

Once the ‘Level 1’ node is created, next step is to click on the node and a pop-up should open for entering details for that node level as shown below

Fig – Clicking on root node ‘Level 1’ a popup opens
[image: Insert node details]

After entering the details in all the tabs and clicking on ‘Accept’ button, the node with default name ‘Level 1’ should change to the value provided in ‘ID’ field and the data in all tabs should get saved in respective tables.

Fig – Entering details in all tabs
[image: Enter node details]

Fig – Clicking on accept button ‘Level 1’ replaced with value given in ‘ID’ field i.e. ‘Bird’
[image: Node name replaced]

Comment: Hey folks .... Someone help pls.... Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like the discussion you have over set the OTN forum at https://community.oracle.com/thread/3767434?sr=stream&ru=1053913 As long as you don't provide all info you don't get any further. A full use case is needed here so that we understand the problem and can help solve it.